# Writing a script that outputs local users and their password expiration date

Tags: command-line, scripting, users, password

I'm supposed to write a script that outputs local users real name and their password expiration information.

This is what I have at the moment. any help would be appreciated.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep '/home' | cut -d: -f5 ;chage -l {} | \
    fgrep "Password expires"'| column -t
```

Comment: This shows a method: http://serverfault.com/questions/295125/dump-output-list-linux-password-expiry-info-for-all-users as well as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660688/how-to-print-al-list-of-user-one-by-one-with-complete-information-in-linux-using

Answer (score 1):

A better way to get local users might be to see if the user has a valid login shell:

```
getent passwd | grep -f /etc/shells
```

Here's something that should work:

```
getent passwd | grep -f /etc/shells | tr ',' ':' | \
    awk -F: '{print $1, $5}' | while read USER NAME 
    do 
        echo $NAME:$(chage -l $USER| awk -F': ' '/Password expires/{print $2}')
    done | column -ts:
```

Using `xargs`, one can do:

```
getent passwd | grep -f /etc/shells | tr ',' ':' | awk -F: '{print $1, $5}' | \
    xargs -L1 bash -c 'echo ${@:2}:$(chage -l $1| awk -F": " "/Password expires/{print \$2}")' : | \
    column -ts:
```

- Using `tr` to replace the `,` with `:` lets us lift the full name from the GECOS field directly.
- `column` can be given an input delimiter with `-s`, which lets us keep multi-word names in one column.
- `-L` makes `xargs` use one *line* of input per command, so that the username and full name are passed to each command.
- `${@:2}` - all the parameters from the second parameter onwards (skipping the first).

Example output:

```
root                      never
Murukesh Mohanan          never
Guest                     never
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` to iterate through the results like this:

```
$ grep '/home' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -n1 -I{} chage -l {} | \
    grep "Password expires" | column -t
Password  expires  :  never
```

In this variation we're calling `xargs` with the `-n1` switch so it'll only call `chage -l` with a single username argument. The `-I{}` tells `xargs` to use `{}` as a macro so that we can mark where we want it to put the arguments when calling `chage`.

Comment: I'd like to retain the same structure in my original posting. is it possible for me to call the chage -l  function without creating a variable?

Comment: There isn't any variable being creates here.

Comment: @slm I think OP is talking about the variables (`while read a b`) that my and Ramesh's answers. OP doesn't want to use variables (dunno why, they're in a subshell and will never affect the main shell), but wants output in a  "name   expiry-date" table form.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d: -f1,3,5 /etc/passwd | while IFS=: read -r user userid fullname
do
    if [ "$userid" -gt 500 ];
    then
    echo "Full Name: $fullname"
    echo "Password Expiry date: $(chage -l "$user" | head -2 | tail -1)"
    fi
done
```

I am just adding the extra step on checking for the local users as `/etc/passwd` file normally contains the system users as well which we do not want. Also, I am using a `while` loop to iterate over the file for better readability.